# Publishing in Visual Studio 2019 - Could not find part of path

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, visual-studio, publishing

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7tdH.png)

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtI3m.png)

Copying file Content\plugins\jquery-ui-bootstrap-masterbs3\css\custom-theme\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\plugins\jquery-ui-bootstrap-masterbs3\css\custom-theme\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png failed. Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\plugins\jquery-ui-bootstrap-masterbs3\css\custom-theme\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png'

i can't publish the web project because of these errors.Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed whether the file or the destination folder exists?

Comment: Yes,It exists both sides and still same error